# Error : 'Module 'ui.router' is not available!'

Tags: angularjs

New to angular js. Dont understand why ui-router is not injected.
Here is my index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='myapp'>
 <head>
 </head>
  <body>
   </body>


 <script src='node_modules/angular/angular.js'></script>
 <script type="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.20/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
 <script src='app/app.js'></script>

</html>
```

And here is my app.js

```js
(function(){
 //allows angular to run
 angular.module('myapp', ['ui.router']);
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you missed `src`, you wrote `type` instead.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.20/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Primarily you did not use`src` in `<script>` tag,
Also you need to specify your  `config`, here is example how to use `ui.router`:

```
(function(){
  //allows angular to run
  var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["ui.router"]);

    myapp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){


      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/")

      $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
            url: "/",
            templateUrl: "home.html"
        })
        .state('detail', {
            url: "/detail",
            templateUrl: "details/detail.html"
        })

    });



  })();
```

live example : http://next.plnkr.co/edit/kHa07oBwnrmxnQ8w?preview